# Local systems are the same as modules over chains of based loop space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, sheaf-theory, cw-complexes, higher-category-theory

Let $M$ be a "good" topological space such as a manifold or a CW complex and assume it's connected. We use $\operatorname{Loc}(M)$ to denote the category of local systems either as a dg category over a field $k$ or a stable category. For this, we mean either representations from the fundamental $\infty$-groupoid $\pi_\infty(M)$ to the coefficient category or the category consists of locally constant sheaves of the same coefficient.

Now pick any point $x \in M$ and one can consider the based loop space $\Omega_x M$ over $x$. This is a group object in spaces by concatenation and thus its chains $C_* (\Omega_x M )$ is a ring. I have the impression that there is the equality
$$\operatorname{Loc}(M) = C_* (\Omega_x M) - \operatorname{Mod}.$$
My questions is where I can find a reference or is there a simple argument of it? I can image, by the point of view of Morita theory, that one can write down a local system which is a compact generator and whose endomorphism is $C_* (\Omega_x M)$, maybe simply the local system which assigns a point $y$ to the ring $C_* (\Omega_y M)$? But I'm confused with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of Koszul duality.  It's probably somewhere in Lurie, but I couldn't pinpoint it, so here's another [reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11724) - lemma 3.9 is what you want.